# Trouble with Chinese character in Solr DataImport

Tags: mysql, jdbc, utf-8, solr, jetty

I am having trouble indexing Chinese/Japanese texts in Solr 3.4. I am importing the data using DIH, the connection block is

```
<dataSource type="JdbcDataSource"
    driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
    url="jdbc:mysql://localhost/db_development?useUnicode=true&amp;characterEncoding=UTF-8&amp;characterSetResults=UTF-8"
    user="user"
    useUnicode="true"
    characterEncoding="UTF-8"
    encoding="UTF-8"
    password="password"
    zeroDateTimeBehavior="convertToNull"
    name="app" />
```

The fieldtype defn of this field goes as

```
  <fieldType name="text_commongrams" class="solr.TextField">
    <analyzer>
      <charFilter class="solr.HTMLStripCharFilterFactory" />
      <tokenizer class="solr.ICUTokenizerFactory" />
      <filter class="solr.ICUTransformFilterFactory" id="Traditional-Simplified"/>
      <filter class="solr.ICUFoldingFilterFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.ICUNormalizer2FilterFactory" name="nfkc_cf" mode="compose"/>
      <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory" />
      <filter class="solr.TrimFilterFactory" />
      <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
      <filter class="solr.SnowballPorterFilterFactory" language="English" protected="protwords.txt"/>
    <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory"
      synonyms="synonyms.txt"
      ignoreCase="true"
      expand="true" />
    <filter class="solr.CommonGramsFilterFactory"
      words="stopwords_en.txt"
      ignoreCase="true" />
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory"
      words="stopwords_en.txt"
      ignoreCase="true" />
    <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory"
      generateWordParts="1"
      splitOnNumerics="0"
      generateNumberParts="1"
      catenateWords="1"
      catenateNumbers="1"
      catenateAll="0"
      preserveOriginal="1" />
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

MySQL character encoding details are as

```
+--------------------------+-----------------------------------------+
| Variable_name            | Value                                   |
+--------------------------+-----------------------------------------+
| character_set_client     | latin1                                  |
| character_set_connection | latin1                                  |
| character_set_database   | latin1                                  |
| character_set_filesystem | binary                                  |
| character_set_results    | latin1                                  |
| character_set_server     | utf8                                    |
| character_set_system     | utf8                                    |
| character_sets_dir       | /opt/local/share/mysql5/mysql/charsets/ |
+--------------------------+-----------------------------------------+
```

I am starting Solr with the java param `-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8`.

The input Text is `JavaOne Tokyo 2012での発表スライド`
When I import it into Solr, and query for that document using ID, I see the text as `JavaOne Tokyo 2012ã§ã®ç™ºè¡¨ã‚¹ãƒ©ã‚¤ãƒ‰`

Can anyone tell me where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 2):

So I finally had to alter my MySQL table to store the strings in UTF8. Details of how to convert an existing table from latin1 to utf8 could be found [here](http://en.gentoo-wiki.com/wiki/Convert_latin1_to_UTF-8_in_MySQL).